# How to return all indexes in multiindex on ANY condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-level

I am trying to wrap my head around multilevel indices.

Specifically, i am trying to get all level 0 indicies that fullfill an 'ANY' criteria.
But i can't for the life of me, understand how to get it to work.

For instance, in the dataframe below, we want all indicies that have a '3' in the column 'test_variable_2'

|  | event_name | test_variable_1 | test_variable_2 | test_variable_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| subject_id |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | pre_event | NaN | 3 | foo |
| 1 | intra_event | 15 | NaN | bar |
| 1 | post_event | 30 | NaN | fum |
| 2 | pre_event | NaN | 2 | foo |
| 2 | intra_event | 45 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | post_event | 60 | NaN | fum |
| 3 | pre_event | NaN | 3 | foo |
| 3 | intra_event_1 | 75 | NaN | bar |
| 3 | intra_event_2 | 90 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | post_event | 105 | NaN | fum |

And the result should be:

|  | event_name | test_variable_1 | test_variable_2 | test_variable_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| subject_id |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | pre_event | NaN | 3 | foo |
| 1 | intra_event | 15 | NaN | bar |
| 1 | post_event | 30 | NaN | fum |
| 3 | pre_event | NaN | 3 | foo |
| 3 | intra_event_1 | 75 | NaN | bar |
| 3 | intra_event_2 | 90 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | post_event | 105 | NaN | fum |

I thought about using the .groupby function, but I am worried that i loose some of the test-variables that contain several values.
The solution i have thus far is to select the indicies that fullfill the boolean mask, and then drop all other indicies, but it seems cumbersome, and not very panda'esque.

I am certain there is a way of harnessing the multilevel indicies. Any pointers in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby().transform`:

```
df[df['test_variable_2'].eq(3).groupby(level=0).transform('any')]
```

Or you can just use `unique` on the valid indexes:

```
df.loc[df[df.test_variable_2.eq(3)].index.unique()]
```

Output:

```
               event_name  test_variable_1  test_variable_2 test_variable_3
subject_id                                                                 
1               pre_event              NaN              3.0             foo
1             intra_event             15.0              NaN             bar
1              post_event             30.0              NaN             fum
3               pre_event              NaN              3.0             foo
3           intra_event_1             75.0              NaN             bar
3           intra_event_2             90.0              NaN             NaN
3              post_event            105.0              NaN             fum
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply! Your last solution also works with several chained conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Try with

```
out = df.loc[df.index.isin(df.index[df['test_variable_2'].eq(3)])]

Out[529]: 
               event_name  test_variable_1  test_variable_2 test_variable_3
subject_id                                                                 
1               pre_event              NaN              3.0             foo
1             intra_event             15.0              NaN             bar
1              post_event             30.0              NaN             fum
3               pre_event              NaN              3.0             foo
3           intra_event_1             75.0              NaN             bar
3           intra_event_2             90.0              NaN             NaN
3              post_event            105.0              NaN             fum
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much.
I don't know how exactly how to rate your and Quang's answer. Both accomplish the job both for single and multiple conditions.

Comment: @JesperMølgaard no worries , just pick the one you like ~ :-) happy coding ~

Answer (score 1):

could chain `.loc` here with `.eq`

Note this will only work with unique index values, it will be safer to add a `unique` clause as @Quang Hoang has suggested.

---

```
df.loc[df.loc[df['test_variable_2'].eq(3)].index]


  event_name  test_variable_1  test_variable_2 test_variable_3
subject_id                                                                 
1               pre_event              NaN              3.0             foo
1             intra_event             15.0              NaN             bar
1              post_event             30.0              NaN             fum
3               pre_event              NaN              3.0             foo
3           intra_event_1             75.0              NaN             bar
3           intra_event_2             90.0              NaN             NaN
3              post_event            105.0              NaN             fum
```

---

also I don't think you have a multi index but if you did, you can replace `index` with `.index.get_level_values(0)` to get the level `0` values then filter by using `isin`

assuming your valid indexes are assigned to a variable called `valid_indexes`

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(valid_indexes,level=0)]
```

Comment: I think this would throw an error when there are more than 1 row with `3` in a group. That's why I put `unique()` in my answer. But it might work for OP's data.

Comment: That is a good solution. It also works if i chain several conditions:
df['test_variable_2']==3)&(df['test_variable_3'] == 'bar')

Comment: @QuangHoang you're right i tihnk it will actually cause the index to increase.